# Sitecore Mock Unit testing throwing conversion error

Tags: unit-testing

Im trying to Mock sitecore item. It throws error cannot convert Moq.Mock to sitecore.Data.Items.Item, any work around for the Moq to work

```
var item= GetMockItem();

_testing.GetChildren(item); --> Throws the above error here

public static Mock<item> GetMockItem()
{
var c= new Mock<Item>();
mockitem.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns("Newitem");
return mockItem.Object;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be wasting your resources on unit testing the framework

Comment: Without knowing what '_testing.GetChildren' is doing, it's hard to say what the issue is. But Mark is right. You shouldn't be unit testing the framework, that's the vendors responsibility.